# Problems with sysdate when year changes

Tags: oracle, date

I'm trying to create a select that can get the name and birthday of all people in a table who have birthdays between today and the next 4 days.

I started at first with this very hardcoded and long code, which theoretically works:

```
select name, birthday from
  (select name, birthday, to_date('DD-MM-YYYY') as today from user_table)
where (extract(month from(birthday)) = extract(month from(today))
  or extract(month from(birthday)) = extract(month from(today+1))
  or extract(month from(birthday)) = extract(month from(today+2))
  or extract(month from(birthday)) = extract(month from(today+3))
  or extract(month from(birthday)) = extract(month from(today+4)))
and (extract(day from(birthday)) = extract(day from(heute))
  or extract(day from(birthday)) = extract(day from(today+1))
  or extract(day from(birthday)) = extract(day from(today+2))
  or extract(day from(birthday)) = extract(day from(today+3))
  or extract(day from(birthday)) = extract(day from(today+4)))
order by extract(month from(birthday)) asc, extract(day from(birthday)) asc
```

The problem with this query is that it also shows people with the beginning days of a month, whenever the "today" variable is at the last day of the month, for example.

One solution which was suggested to me was to use the "between" function, changing this query slightly:

```
select name, birthday from
  (select name, birthday, to_date('DD-MM-YYYY') as today from user_table)
where (extract(month from(birthday)) between extract(month from(today)) and extract(month from(today+4)))
and (extract(day from(birthday)) between extract(day from(today)) and extract(day from(today+4)))
order by extract(month from(birthday)) asc, extract(day from(birthday)) asc
```

Though when I run this at, say, "31-12-2017", whenever the year or month changes, I get no results back.

I also tried doing some heavier calculation, as trying to bring the current "today" date back to the "birtday" with the  `add_months` function, so I wouldn't have to use any extra conditions to check the day and month.
But it never returns the date correctly (on cases of last day of the month/year). This is the code example I made:

```
select name, birthday, add_months(today, -month_difference) as today_minus_difference from
  (select name, birthday, today, floor(months_between(today, birthday)) as month_difference from
    (select name, birthday, to_date('DD-MM-YYYY') as today from table_users)
  )
where birthday between add_months(today, -month_difference) and add_months(today+4, -month_difference)
order by extract(month from(birthday)) asc, extract(day from(birthday)) asc;
```

Is there something that I'm missing from the `between` function? Can't it calculate a `between` date when it changes months or years in it? Or am I missing something else in the logic?

EDIT: Some people asked how I handled the leap years, here's the final query with which I ended up going. I'm sure it could be improved, but it worked on both cases (year change and leap years).

```
select name, birthday
from users
  (select to_date(input_date) + rownum - 1 as today from dual connect by level <=5)
where to_char(birthday, 'dd.mm') = to_char(today, 'dd.mm')
union
select name, birthday
from users
  (select to_date(input_date) as today from dual)
where where to_char(birthday, 'dd.mm') = to_char(today, 'dd.mm')
or birthday between (add_months(today, -((extract(year from(today)) - extract(year from(birthday)))*12)))
and (add_months(today+4, -((extract(year from(today)) - extract(year from(geburtstag)))*12)))
```

order by birthday;

I would've used just the first part and add the "between" condition, but it kept bringing duplicate results. I might've missed something, but it still works fine with these solutions with Union.

Comment: How should birthdays of February 29 be handled? Those are more troublesome than SYSDATE being close to the end of the year, I think. What is the requirement (in words), anyway?

Comment: You just got drifted away using too many unnecessary constructs when the solution was much simple.

Comment: I'm not quite sure yet. I guess I'll try adding more dates that include the 29th as a birthday and see the results. I wonder if there could be a case to calculate when we are in a leap year

Comment: @mathguy the only "requirement" I got for this function/select is that this query should work under any circumstance. I'm just now learning, after a quick search, how one can find a leap year, but I really don't know yet how I'll be handling it in a select. I'm considering maybe and If or Case inside a select, though I'm still struggling to work these into a query.

Comment: My question wasn't how you will be handling in code. My question was, what is the specification from the user who requested this? (Very likely they didn't think about it either, and they need to, and they need to tell you what they concluded). Namely: I was born on Feb. 29, 1980. (I wasn't but let's say I was). Today is Feb. 27, 2017. Does my birthday fall between today and March 3, 2017? Matching on month and day won't work, since 2017 does not have Feb. 29.

Comment: @mathguy I might've gotten confused with the question. The only thing I was told was to get birthdays from today up to 4 days in the future, regardless of situation or problems in the way (like last day of month/year and now leap years).

In the example you mentioned, yes it would fail since the 29th doesn't exist in the 2017 year listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you choose a hard way while simple & clear exists:

```
select
  name,
  birthdate
from
  user_table,
  (select sysdate + rownum - 1 check_date from dual connect by level <= 5)
where   
  to_char(birthdate, 'dd.mm') = to_char(check_date, 'dd.mm')
```

Comment: Well, ... When do people born February 29 usually celebrate their birthday?

Comment: That's excellent question, thanks. I'm not sure, how author will answer, but it's definitely should be in care.

Comment: Awesome, it did work. Though I'm trying to understand every part of the code. The rownum and connect by level <= 5 are meant to run a select from the sysdate + 4, right?

I'm not that familiar with these functions so I'm trying to better grasp them

Comment: @AWildmann - pay no attention to the subquery with the CONNECT BY - it looks scary, but all it does is it generates a micro-table with one column, check_date, and with five rows, one each for "today", "today + 1", up to "today + 4". At some point you will learn that technique - it will come naturally - but right now just accept that it's a way to generate these dates, and focus on the REST of the query first. Make sure you understand THAT.